# Add standalone directive to Jackson XML serialization

Tags: java, xml, jackson, jaxb

I'm trying to get Jackson to produce an XML header like JAXB does, but I can't figure out how to add the "standalone='yes'?"

Example:

```
public class XmlTest {

    @XmlRootElement
    public static class Book {

    }

    @Test
    public void testBookXml() throws JsonProcessingException {
        XmlMapper mapper = new XmlMapper();
        mapper.configure(ToXmlGenerator.Feature.WRITE_XML_DECLARATION, true);

        System.out.println("Jackson\n" + mapper.writeValueAsString(new Book()) + "\n");

        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        JAXB.marshal(new Book(), sw);
        System.out.println("JAXB\n" + sw.toString());
    }
}
```

The output is this:

```
Jackson
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><Book/>

JAXB
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<book/>
```

I don't care about `<Book/> vs <book/>`. Other than String manipulation, is there a way to get the Jackson header to be like the JAXB one?

Comment: did you manage to resolve this?

Comment: I ended up just doing a string replace on the result. Couldn't figure out how to do it using JAXB.

Comment: sad to hear it, but tnx for reply

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same problem and I have resolved this problem by reloading the class `BufferingXmlWriter` (copy from source code and modify a method), the reloading must before that you use Jackson to produce an XML

1. Create package com.ctc.wstx.sw and create class `BufferingXmlWriter`
2. Copy source code from real `com.ctc.wstx.sw.BufferingXmlWriter`
3. Modify method
   `writeXmlDeclaration(String version, String encoding, String standalone)`

```java
public void writeXmlDeclaration(String version, String encoding, String standalone)
            throws IOException
 {
       // final char chQuote = (mUseDoubleQuotesInXmlDecl ? '"' : '\'');
        final char chQuote = '"';
    
        fastWriteRaw("<?xml version=");
        fastWriteRaw(chQuote);
        fastWriteRaw(version);
        fastWriteRaw(chQuote);
    
        if (encoding != null && encoding.length() > 0) {
            fastWriteRaw(" encoding=");
            fastWriteRaw(chQuote);
            fastWriteRaw(encoding);
            fastWriteRaw(chQuote);
        }
        if (standalone == null) {
            fastWriteRaw(" standalone=");
            fastWriteRaw(chQuote);
            fastWriteRaw("yes");
            fastWriteRaw(chQuote);
        }
        fastWriteRaw('?', '>');
 }
```

4. Reload

   ```
    Class.forName("com.ctc.wstx.sw.BufferingXmlWriter");
   ```
5. Result

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If you want exactly as JaxB then solution provided by @gongxiansheng would work.

But if you are looking for **double quoted XML declaration** like me and have default Woodstox dependency then below setting will just be fine:

```
    XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
    xmlMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);  // for Pretty print or formatting
    xmlMapper.configure(ToXmlGenerator.Feature.WRITE_XML_DECLARATION, true);
    xmlMapper.getFactory().getXMLOutputFactory().setProperty(WstxOutputProperties.P_USE_DOUBLE_QUOTES_IN_XML_DECL, true);
    String reqXml = xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(new MyRequestDetail());
```

This will result in double quoted xml declaration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

**Note:** More configurations are listed here on this excellent article: [Configuring Woodstox XML parser: Woodstox-specific properties](https://cowtowncoder.medium.com/configuring-woodstox-xml-parser-woodstox-specific-properties-1ce5030a5173)