# SpringBoot/Jackson 2.13.x - outputting standalone="yes" in XML Header

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, jackson2

I'm configuring my ObjectMapper/XmlMessageConverter in Spring Boot with the following Beans:

```
    @Bean
    public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder()
    {
        final AnnotationIntrospector introspector = new JaxbAnnotationIntrospector(TypeFactory.defaultInstance());
        return new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder().serializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL).defaultUseWrapper(false)
                                                .annotationIntrospector(introspector);
    }
    
    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder)
    {
        final XmlMapper xmlMapper = builder.createXmlMapper(true).build();
        xmlMapper.configure(ToXmlGenerator.Feature.WRITE_XML_DECLARATION, true);
        xmlMapper.getFactory().getXMLOutputFactory().setProperty(WstxOutputProperties.P_USE_DOUBLE_QUOTES_IN_XML_DECL, true);
        return new MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter(xmlMapper);
    }
```

But I can't seem to find a way for force the output of standalone="yes" into the xml header.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: Why do you want this to be set? It only has meaning if there is a DTD declaration as well else it is useless. Also this configuration overrides the default jackson configuration so it might even interfere with other parts of the Spring Boot setup.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [jackson](/questions/tagged/jackson) can do it only with a (custom) `BufferingXmlWriter`:

- https://www.google.com/search?q=xmlmapper+add+standalone
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/63505475/592355
- http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-dataformat-xml/javadoc/2.13/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/xml/ser/ToXmlGenerator.Feature.html

But you have "spring alternatives":

- [`Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/xml/Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter.html)
- alternatively [`MarshallingHttpMessageConverter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/xml/MarshallingHttpMessageConverter.html) in combination with [spring-oxm](/questions/tagged/spring-oxm).

..can achieve it/have it as default.

- https://www.google.com/search?q=spring+boot+xml+standalone%3Dyes